# Attempting to convert List<List<>> to Object[][]

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automated-tests, dataprovider

Currently trying to convert a List> to Object[][] for the means of testing multiple tests from an excel sheet. This is the code I have at the moment.

```
@DataProvider(name = "Journey")
    public Object[][] generateJourneys() {
    Object[][] o = TestVariables.sourceSheet.toArray();
    return o;
    }
```

The DataProvider should end up looking something like

```
    {
       {"TableEntry1", "TableEntry2", "TableEntry3"},
       {"TableEntry12", "TableEntry13", "TableEntry14"}
    }
```

I have a separate method to pull the excel file like this.

```
List<List<String>> sourceSheet = ExcelFileHandler.readFromFile("src/resourceSheet.xls");
```

So I can pull as the following code to get the first row, second column

```
  sourceSheet.get(0).get(1);
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Iterate over the lists and create and fill the arrays as needed. Any problems with that?

Comment: You've got JSON there, not an excel spreadsheet

Comment: The question is how do I convert <List<List<String>> to Object[][] so they

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood the problem, you need to convert List of List to Object[][].

Try this

```
Object[][] convert(List<List<Object>> lists) {
    Object[][] array = new Object[lists.size()][];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = new Object[lists.get(i).size()];
        lists.get(i).toArray(array[i]);
    }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: This has worked a charm, thank you very much! apologies for the vagueness, hungover working today.  haha

Answer (score 6):

How about

```
String[][] o = sourceSheet.stream()
    .map(l -> l.stream().toArray(String[]::new))
    .toArray(String[][]::new);
```

For each nested list in sourceSheet a new array will be created, copied and added to o

Comment: I don't know if I will ever use streams that way, but still; impressive ;-)